# Lazy_high_chart: why options.xaxis undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, highcharts

I work with ror and use lazy_high_chart gem.
my view code is :

```
%= high_stock("my_id", @h) do |c| %>     
   <%="options.rangeSelector= {inputEditDateFormat: '%b %e, %Y',buttons: [{type: 'month',count: 1,text: '1m'}, {type: 'month',count: 3,text: '3m'}, {type: 'month',count: 6,text: '6m'}, {type: 'year',count: 1,text: '1y'}, {type: 'all',text: 'All'}]}"%>
    <%="options.xAxis.events.setExtremes = function() { alert 'ho';}" %>

<%end %>
```

The rangeSelector setting is o.k but when I add the xaxis events(or xaxis.other parameter)
I got an error

**"options.xAxis  is undefined"**

In the  gem readme file I saw very similar exemple:
https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your controller code look like?

Comment: I succeeded.(I added an answer for this question)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add :

```
   <%="options.xAxis.events = {}" %>
```

before:

```
   <%="options.xAxis.events.setExtremes = function() { alert 'ho';}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better follow it's steps and use it in controller, not in view.

https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts

e.g.
In controller,

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
end
```

In view,

```
<%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>
```